# How to convert split words into lowercase

Tags: javascript

How do i convert words i have split into lowercase ? I have the following code.

```js
var title = 'The Quick brown fox';

var titleCase = [];


var Titlewords = title.split("");

for (var i = 0; i < Titlewords.length; i++) {
    Titlewords[i].toLowerCase();

    console.log(Titlewords[i]);

}
```

Comment: to split the words I guess you have to split by `" "` (space) instead of `""` empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to assign `Titlewords[i].toLowerCase()` back to `Titlewords[i]`

```js
var title = 'The Quick brown fox';

var titleCase = [];


var Titlewords = title.split("");

for (var i = 0; i < Titlewords.length; i++) {
Titlewords[i] = Titlewords[i].toLowerCase();

console.log(Titlewords[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot of things in JavaScript without writing loops by yourself. This is just another example.

```
const title = 'The Quick brown fox';
const words = title.split(' ').map(word => word.toLowerCase());

// print the array
console.log(words);

// print the single words
words.forEach(word => console.log(word));
```

**Resources**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the value

```
Titlewords[i] = Titlewords[i].toLowerCase();
```

```js
var title = 'The Quick brown fox';

var titleCase = [];


var Titlewords = title.split("");

for (var i = 0; i < Titlewords.length; i++) {
    Titlewords[i] = Titlewords[i].toLowerCase();

    console.log(Titlewords[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.toLowerCase()` returns a string, not sets it to lower. What you want to do is

```
Titlewords[i] = Titlewords[i].toLowerCase();
```